Attempting to Install a Nuget Package and I get an error
I'm trying to install a nuget package.  And I get the following error.
Each package is licensed to you by its owner. NuGet is not responsible for, nor does it grant any licenses to, third-party packages. Some packages may include dependencies which are governed by additional licenses. Follow the package source (feed) URL to determine any dependencies.

Package Manager Console Host Version 6.10.2.8

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> NuGet\Install-Package NAudio.Lame -Version 2.1.0


Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'NAudio.Lame.2.1.0' with respect to project 'abc.Win', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8'
NuGet\Install-Package : Package 'NAudio.Lame 2.1.0' is not found in the following primary source(s): 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\,https://nuget.devexpress.com/ofhzGulIyleBlp5uTgWWzbmOCuhPO
gs7vTSK8fjEKrl59uebCY/api/v3/index.json,C:\Program Files\DevExpress 
24.1\Components\System\Components\Packages'. Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) 
package id, version are specified correctly.
At line:1 char:1
+ NuGet\Install-Package NAudio.Lame -Version 2.1.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPa 
   ckageCommand
 
Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.8455023

I've done installations like this before, and it worked.  How do I fix this error?
I'm expecting the nuget package installation to execute without errors.  This way, the following code will not show any errors.
Shared Sub ConvertWAVtoMP3(inputWavPath As String, outputMp3Path As String)
    Using reader = New WaveFileReader(inputWavPath)

        Using writer = New LameMP3FileWriter(outputMp3Path, reader.WaveFormat, LAMEPreset.STANDARD)
            reader.CopyTo(writer)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub


Hi @RayT, have you tried to download this package directly from nuget website and put it into local source and install it from local source?


Package 'NAudio.Lame 2.1.0' is not found in the following primary source(s)

It seems that this version of the package NAudio.Lame is not hosted on your sources you have configured in NuGet.Config file.
Please check whether the package exists on your sources one by one. If this package are not hosted in the source lists above, please add a new source in your config file. (Windows: %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config)
For example
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

You can use Source to specify the URL or folder path for the package source to search or set it in Package Manager Console.
Install-Package NAudio.Lame -Version 2.1.0 -Source "xxx"


Update-1

Is there a way to do a complete reset and start from scratch for naudio?

1.Create a new .NET project(e.g:ClassLibrary).
2.Select Clear All NuGet Cache(s) from Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings menu command in VS.
3.Clear the content of the file NuGet.Config and copy the following to the file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
   <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"  />
  </packageSources>
  
</configuration>

Note: You can backup the Nuget.Config file before clearing it.
4.Try to install the package with PMC again. If it fails, please share the error messages.
Besides, try to use Nuget Package Manager UI or dotnet/PackageReference to see if you can install successfully.
dotnet add package NAudio.Lame --version 2.1.0 

<PackageReference Include="NAudio.Lame" Version="2.1.0" />

Docs Referred:
Clear local folders
Update-2
Try to download the package directly from nuget website and put the package into your local feed then install this package from local feed to see if you can install this package successfully.
1.Create a folder to store your nuget packages and put NAudio.Lame package into the folder. This is your local feed. You can install packages from here later instead of nuget.org.
For example:
"c:\testpackages"
2.Open Nuget.config file and add a custom package source.
Windows: %appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config
 <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
     <add key="Test Source" value="c:\testpackages" />
  </packageSources>

3.Select the Package source:"local source" to install this package.


I've tried that and it still fails.  Is there a way to do a complete reset and start from scratch for naudio?

Hi @RayT, updated the answer.
